# Deploying a simple Java Spark web app

Tags: java, maven, deployment, web-deployment

I have tried this simple "Hello World" web app (set using maven) in [Setting up Spark with Maven](https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/04/02/setting-up-a-spark-project-with-maven.html#eclipse), using Eclipse in a Windows platform. It works perfectly if it is run from Eclipse.

But what I want to achieve is to make it run in a CentOS 6.x I have in the cloud, to which I access via ssh using putty. I already have installed, in CentOS, the JDK 8 and maven. I do not have any Application Server installed (no Tomcat, etc) because I want the Spark app be run with its embedded AS (which is Jetty).

I haven't found yet how to deploy such a Spark app from Eclipse/Maven/Windows to a CentOS server in the cloud. I found some tutorials explaining how to deploy on heraku, or even on how to deploy it in a different AS (no using the embedded one), but nothing that simple as what I want to achieve, as explained.

In Eclipse, if I export the project as a jar, and I upload the jar to the CentOS server, running it with 'java -jar appname.jar' does not work, it seems it does not have Spark libraries nor the embedded Jetty.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: What is the output from running `java -jar appname.jar` on the server?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: spark/Request
        at chatapp.Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: spark/Request
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spark.Request
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more`

Comment: Thus it seems the jar does not contain the Spark libraries, as I said.

Comment: I believe what you said, but the stacktrace is relevant to your question, and helps others when they search for things like `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: spark/Request`, so including it here is beneficial.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

After watching a video tutorial about maven, I have found the solution.
First, you need to add the following to the xml.pom file in your maven project in Eclipse:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <!-- This tells Maven to include all dependencies -->
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>chatapp.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

It is important to tell maven where to find the main class. In my case, I named my app chatapp (because I'm planning to evolve this simple 'Hello World' app into a chat app), and the Main class containing the main method is also named Main, which is under the package chatapp, thus it is chatapp.Main. You can add these lines right after the `<dependencies>` node. Therefore the pom file should look like this:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.orboan</groupId>
<artifactId>chatapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>new-spark-project</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <!-- This tells Maven to include all dependencies -->
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>chatapp.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now, the important thing is NOT to use the export utility in Eclipse (right click on the project in the package explorer and from contextual menu do not choose Export) as you usually do when you want to export a java project into a jar file for deployment. This will generate a jar file, but without all dependencies needed.

Instead, you have to choose (from the contextual menu) Run As > Maven Install. This will generate (from the pom.xml) the corresponding jar file with all needed dependencies included, in my case `chatapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`.

Then, upload that jar file to the CentOS server and just run it with `java -jar

chatapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. It should work, now.